# In JSP radio button exception

Tags: jsp, radio-button

I made two radio buttons like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="One" value="Send To All" checked="checked" />  
    <input type="radio" name="One" value="Send To Recent" />
```

But when I tried to fetch the value of radio button via following line of code:

```
request.getParameter("Send To All");
```

I got a `NullPointerException` on the same line. So can anyone tell me the right way to get the value of radio button?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually on server side we can access the form values by `name` attribute not with the `value` attribute

So it should be

```
request.getParameter("One");
```

And the line it self won't give null pointer exception and it returns null value if there is no parameter with that name.

And as commented you have to check like

```
    if(request.getParameter("One").equals("Send To All"){
       //TO DO
    }
```

Comment: And one more thing you gave "Send To All"  on client side and checking with "SendToAll" on server side which never gives true .

Answer (score 0):

it should be `request.getParameter("One");`

Comment: this will not helping me at all... the final thing i want to do is to:

if(request.getParameter("One") == "SendToAll")  

But it is not going inside if(). What i am doing wrong here

Comment: take a look at @The Suresh Atta last comments. you need to compare with "Send To All" rather than "SendToAll"

Answer (score 0):

```
String value= request.getParameter("One");// used to get the value 
out.println(value);
```

it will work